# Uninstall and update from kernel that 'Could not be found in Mainline kernel installer'

Tags: kernel, 22.04

My system Wifi has been having serious issues since upgrading to 22.04. I've seen that this issue has come up a few times so I've been trying to install a new kernel with the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer. [image: Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer]

However, after I update it seems I'm still running on an old kernel, after installing the newest updated kernels. When I try to press 'Uninstall Old', I get the error: [image: Could not find running kernel in list].

Is there some reason for my current kernel not being in the Mainline list? How do I update the kernel to the most recent fitting version? Is the Wifi issue for the kernel I am using (5.14.0-1048-oem) known?

Comment: Consider asking a separate question about the wifi problem. Odds are there is a better fix than this. Give specifics of your wifi card when you ask.

Comment: It is unclear what is your wireless device. Please add this information. Ubuntu doesn't use mainline kernels.

Comment: I've made a new post here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426551/wifi-adapter-not-performing-well-on-ubuntu-22-04